How can I deploy a helm packaged app to ArgoCD?
I'm working on migrating a web application (nautobot) to a google anthos k8s management platform.
The anthos work flow does not use helm, instead it uses kustomize to specify dependencies and resources which are used by argocd to provision necessary pods.
What's the best approach to do this migration? Do I just need take all the config files from nautobot's helm chart repo and add them to my app config repo?
Sorry if the question is unclear. Still trying to wrap my head around it!

Your question is basically: How to migrate from Helm to ArgoCD + Kustomize?

First, use helm template <path/to/chart/dir> to generate all plain kubernetes manifests.
Then create an YAML file for each of these manifests. (You could also put all of them in a single file, as is, but that's not elegant)

Then you'd have an structure like this:
file1.yaml
file2.yaml
file3.yaml
...

Create a kustomization.yaml in the same directory, with the following contents:
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://json.schemastore.org/kustomization
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- file1.yaml
- file2.yaml
- file3.yaml

Now you can create an ArgoCD application that consumes this kustomization.yaml file (There's plenty of documentation elsewhere about this process).
